# Python pygraphviz not working due to dot not found in path

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am trying to get the [fast-autocomplete library](https://github.com/wearefair/fast-autocomplete) to work. I have a `virtualenv` with `Python 3.6` installed for this. Everything else works but when I am trying to visualize the graph, I keep getting the following error:

```py
    File "/Users/rishi/code/search-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1569, in _which
        raise ValueError("No prog %s in path." % name)
    ValueError: No prog dot in path.
```

I have already installed the following:

- `pygraphviz` and `graphviz` as suggested [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4911) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987353/python-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path).
- `pydot` installed with `dot` at `/usr/local/bin/dot`

I am on OSx Mojave. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you get when run `dot -V` in your terminal?

Comment: @Dany I get: dot - graphviz version 2.43.0 (0)

Comment: That's strange. And if you run `os.environ["PATH"]` in your python interpreter inside vitualenv, do you get that `/usr/local/bin` included there?

Comment: Yes. '/Users/rishi/code/search-env/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/rishi/miniconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin'

Comment: Ok, and just to be sure, if you `from pygraphviz import AGraph` and then `AGraph._which(None, 'dot')`, do you still get an error? (all inside virtualenv, of course)

Comment: Weirdly no. But when I try and use the same virtualenv in my Eclipse and run it, I get the error. Do you think it is more of an Eclipse issue than dot one?